# Run-time error transposing countif sum to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

What is triggering a 1004 error for the following code?

Code:

```
        wsR As Worksheet
        Set wsR = Sheets("Rec_9")        
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
               
        Dim LastRowD As Long
        Dim LastRowJ As Long
        LastRowD = wsR.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LastRowJ = wsR.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Sheet1.Range("d2").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsR.Range("D2:LastRowD"), "[string1]")
        Sheet1.Range("e2").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsR.Range("D2:LastRowD"), "[string2]")
        Sheet1.Range("f2").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsR.Range("D2:LastRowD"), "[string3]")
        Sheet1.Range("g2").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsR.Range("D2:LastRowD"), "[string4]")
```

The aim is to transpose sums of chosen strings from one sheet to another, in the same workbook. At first, I thought the ranges weren't sourced (specified sheets) or defined (indefinite end) appropriately, but still it recurs.

I don't get it.

Comment: Do not put variables inside of the quotes. They aren't variables then. `wsR.Range("D2:D" & LastRowD)` - that's what you are trying to do... whether is actually does what you want is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not put variables inside of the quotes. They aren't variables then. They just become part of a literal string then. Instead, concatenate them using `&` - then it will use the value of `LastRowD` and put it at the end of the first string.

You need to specify the column on both sides of the `:` too...

```
wsR.Range("D2:D" & LastRowD)
```

That's what you are trying to do... whether is actually does what you want is for you to decide. That will at least address the Run Time Error, which was your question.